# Web UI redirection issue

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

I am running IBM Cloud Private using 5 VMs on my laptop. My home network subnet is `192.168.100` whereas the subnet used by all 5 VMs is `192.168.142`. I am port forwarding 8443 from the VMware Workstation from host to the master node which is `192.168.142.103`. My laptop IP is `192.168.100.201`.

I was hoping that I should be able to access this Web UI from any other machine in my home network and I tried this URL from other machine:

```
https://192.168.100.201:8443
```

And, it directs properly to the guest VM as I see the url changes to :

```
https://192.168.100.201:8443/console/
```

But, after few seconds, I get the message that the site cannot be reached. I noticed that the url has changed from original host laptop address of `192.168.100.201` address to the Guest VM address `192.168.142.103` as shown:

```
https://192.168.142.103:8443/idauth/oidc/endpoint/OP/authorize?client_id=617a0480d5e506a5e797f852bea1df38&response_type=code&scope=openid%20email%20profile&redirect_uri=https://192.168.100.201:8443/auth/liberty/callback
```

This seems like that the redirection in the Web UI is not handled properly.

However, I installed `kubectl` for Windows on another machine and I did the port 8001 forward from `192.168.100.201` to the VM's master Guest `192.168.142.103` and added `kubectl set config` commands (from web UI `Client Configure` option) on my other laptop (`192.168.100.202`).

```
kubectl config set-cluster pot_icp_cluster.icp --server=https://192.168.100.201:8001 --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true
kubectl config set-context pot_icp_cluster.icp-context --cluster=pot_icp_cluster.icp
kubectl config set-credentials admin --token=<token>
kubectl config set-context pot_icp_cluster.icp-context --user=admin --namespace=default
kubectl config use-context pot_icp_cluster.icp-context
```

And, this works perfect as I am able to run `kubectl` commands from the other laptop (`192.168.100.202`) to the VMs running on another laptop (`192.168.100.201`) using port forwarding same way I did for the Web UI.

My question is: Is there something that I can do to get this redirection problem fixed in the Web UI?

Answer (score 0):

I received a reply from an expert that liberty server that authenticates and verifies a login has only the master node's IP address registered with it as a callback URL during the installation. In the version of IBM Cloud Private 2.1.0.1, there is no direct way to register the new clients. However, this limitation is being fixed and starting next upgrade, we should be able to register new clients dynamically post install also.